# React/reselect how to refresh ui before a selector is recomputed

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

In my React-App (create-react-app) I use a selector (created with reselect) to compute derived data from stored data.
The Problem is, the selector takes a long time to compute. I would like to show a spinner (or a message) on the user interface. But each time the selector is recomputed the ui freezes.

I read a lot of stuff (Web Worker, requestIdleCallback, requestAnimationFrame) and try to make my own React hook but I am stuck. I cannot use the selector in callbacks.

The searched result is simply to get the ui refreshed before the selector is recomputed.

Comment: Any code? It's hard to tell what's going on without any info.

Comment: I was now able to get something that works. But no idea if that "good". Should I "answer my question"? Or "edit my question" and post the code and ask if this is "good practice"?

Comment: You can answer yourself if you think the question and the answer are both clear, readable, easy to understand, and useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my solution. I don't know if it's "good" or if it breaks some rules of react or reselect, but it works. Maybe you can assess that?
The code is simplified to improve readability.

The idea is, the selector returns a Promise and I call `requestAnimationFrame` before computing the data to get a chance to refresh the ui.

selector.js:

```js
const dataSelector = state => state.data;

export const getDataComputedPromise = createSelector([dataSelector], (data) => {
    const compute = function () {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            // heavy computing stuff
            resolve(computedData);
        });
    };

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let start = null;
        let requestId = null;
        function step (timestamp) {
            if (!start) {
                start = timestamp;
                window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
                requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
                return;
            };
            compute().then(freeResources => {
                window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
                resolve(freeResources);
            });
        }
        requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    });
});
```

myPage.js

```js
const MyPage = ({ someProps }) => {
    ...
    const dataComputedPromise = useSelector(getDataComputedPromise);
    const [dataComputed, setDataComputed] = useState([]);
    const [computeSelector, setComputeSelector] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setComputeSelector(true);
    }, [data]);
    useEffect(() => {
        dataComputedPromise.then(dataComputed => {
            setDataComputed(dataComputed);
            setComputeSelector(false);
        });
    }, [dataComputedPromise]);
    ...
    return <div>
        <Loader active={compueSelector}>Computing data...</Loader>
    </div>;
};

export default MyPage;
```